# Dynamically updating/refreshing a KmlLayer

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to render postal codes on a Google map from spatial coordinate data. Since there are a lot of coordinates, I would like to dynamically load only the coordinates applicable on the observable map.

I'm trying to something like this:

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://example.com/my.kml'
  });

  ctaLayer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {

      var ne_lat = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
      var ne_lng = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();

      if(typeof ctaLayer !== 'undefined') {
            ctaLayer.setMap(null);
      }

      var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://example.com/my.kml?ne_lat=' + ne_lat + '&ne_lng=' + ne_lng;
      });
      ctaLayer.setMap(map);

});
```

The problem is, is when I try to move or zoom the map, it just kicks me back to where I was before (zooms back out, or re-centers the map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KmlLayer auto centers on the data by default.  If you don't want it to change the zoom/center set the preserveViewport option to true.

(plus you have a syntax error in your code)

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://example.com/my.kml',
    preserveViewport: true
  });

  ctaLayer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {

      var ne_lat = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
      var ne_lng = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();

      if(typeof ctaLayer !== 'undefined') {
            ctaLayer.setMap(null);
      }

      var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://example.com/my.kml?ne_lat=' + ne_lat + '&ne_lng=' + ne_lng,,
        preserveViewport: true
      });
      ctaLayer.setMap(map);

});
```

Comment: The map doesn't display when I put `presrveViewport` on my first instantiation of the KmlLayer. Putting it only within `bounds_changed` works. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't provide your `mapOptions`, that probably doesn't include the mandatory center and zoom parameters (which KmlLayer sets when preserveViewport is false).

Comment: Yep. Didn't have the `zoom` parameter set.